# ajax :populating 2 drop down boxes via ajax using value of the third one

Tags: javascript, ajax, select, combobox

i hava a html page with 3 drop down boxes. When i change one of the box the value in that box is sent to server and the server shold returns the values of the other 2.
How will i populate the othere 2 drop down boxes depending on the value of first one.
All valuses are obtained frm server side.

EX dd1 , dd2, dd3  where dd= drop down box

if dd1 is changes the value in dd1 is sent to server and server shold return the value of other 2.How can i pouplate dd2 and dd3?
In what form server  shold reply

Plz note:I am using plain ajax and i am not nor i want to use jquery and other frameworks.
I am looking for a solution in trival ajax.

Comment: Are you using a JS library? if so, which one?

Comment: Dear if plain ajax or even Javascript is that trivial, we will not have all those frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Make your AJAX request and then if the response is successful, take the response data and insert into the correct position in the DOM. How straightforward it will be to insert the response will depend on the response type and format.

That's the general process in using AJAX